# How to integrate Vaadin 7.3.9 into a Grails project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, grails, vaadin

I am experiencing some troubles with the Vaadin integration into a Grails project in Eclipse.

I am using the Eclipse (version 4.4 Luna) provided by Spring Tool Suite (version 3.6.3) and Grails (version 2.4.4).

I create a Grails project:

- File -> New -> Grails Project

I am reading the Vaadin Cookbook book, the author says that in order to use Vaadin in a Grails project, the Vaadin plugin for Grails must be installed. The author says that one should:

- Open the grails console and type:
  `grails> install-plugin vaadin`

However, this is deprecated as of Grails 2.4.3, and the plugin must be added to the BuildConfig.groovy file like this (basing on this tutorial of one of the co-authors of the book -> https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%20on%20Grails%20-%20Create%20project%20in%20IntelliJ%20IDEA (IntelliJIDEA is used in the linked URL instead of Eclipse)):

```
// BuildConfig.groovy
// ...
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
     //...
      plugins {
          //...
          compile ":vaadin:7.3.9"
          //...
      }
}
```

But then, what should I do? In the book they say that the `grails-app/vaadin` folder must be marked as the source folder (`Build Path -> Use as source folder`), but there's no such folder in my Grails project.

Also, from the tutorial with InlliJIDEA linked above, the author says:

[image]

Now I have tried to edit the UrlMappings.groovy file in order to remove all the mappings:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

    }
}
```

And then when I run the `run-app` command I get the following exception:

```
|Running Grails application
objc[42370]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
| Error 2015-01-30 11:33:56,213 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
->>  760 | defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    142 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|    455 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|     73 | access$100 in     ''
|    367 | run . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|    361 | run       in     ''
|    360 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    424 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    269 | configure in javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl
|    111 | buildDefaultValidatorFactory in javax.validation.Validation
|    266 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
->>  372 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    361 | run       in     ''
|    360 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    424 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    760 | defineClass in     ''
|    142 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|    455 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|     73 | access$100 in     ''
|    367 | run . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|    361 | run       in     ''
|    360 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    424 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    269 | configure in javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl
|    111 | buildDefaultValidatorFactory in javax.validation.Validation
|    266 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/vaadin-in-grails
```

It says "Server running" at the end but it is not true, and no `grails-app/vaadin` folder is created as needed.

I didn't find any other tutorials which cover the topic (specifically I was searching for an Eclipse version of the IntelliJIDEA tutorial I linked, but didn't find it).

So, as I know that the book I am reading covers an older version of Grails where plugins are installed via the `install-plugin` deprecated command and I can't use it and as I have tried to use the `compile ":vaadin:7.3.9"` directive without success, I am asking someone of SO here.

How can I resolve this issue and start programming with Grails/Vaadin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the install-plugin method.

Place this in the plugins section in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
 compile ":vaadin:7.4.1"
```

From what I understand from the plugin author, the newer versions of the Vaadin/Grails plugin no longer create the grails-app/vaadin directory. Instead, you're now expected to place your vaadin code in the typical src/groovy or src/java folders.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know that version `7.4.1` is now available! Yes, `grails-app/vaadin` is not used anymore, now we can create a simple quick-start UI using the grails `vaadin-quickstart` target.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the site where you find this information?

Comment: @flp Sorry for the late answer to your comment, I have seen it only now. Anyway, at the time I was resolved the issue, there wasn't a site which described the complete steps to set up a working vaadin/grails project yet, so I ended up opening an issue on GitHub: the following links should help -> https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/issues/48
and https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPVAADIN-25

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, I had the same problem but after reading a lot the book Vaadin on Grails and experimenting a lot I came across with the solution, it's important to mention that my grails project is using this configurations, no major changes in version so I believe it should work:

- Grails 2.4.5
- Vaadin 7.4.8, which is a bit newer,
- Oracle Express for Database (this is agnostic)

From your log trace, I see this line:

```
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
```

OK, first things first, go to your BuildConfig.groovy and set this values:

```
//BuildConfig.groovy

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55.2" // or ":tomcat:8.0.20"

    // plugins for the compile step
    //compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
    compile ":vaadin:7.4.8"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    //runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
}
```

What you have to notice from above code are two things:

1. Plugins section is using hibernate4:4.3.6.1
2. In Dependencies section I added following line, from my many reads some people mentioned that due the change from Hibernate3 to Hibernate4 there were some changes in the specification in order to meet some standards (here the javax.validation API was deprecated), so this is the line that solves your problem:
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'

Now in your file DataSource.groovy, take care of this points:
 1. As you remember I set project to use Hibernate4, so the propper configuration should be done.

```
//DataSource.groovy
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    username = "db_user"
    password = "db_password"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
    jdbc.use_get_generated_keys = true
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the section hibernate you have to set the value for:

```
cache.region.factory_class
```

In my case I'm using Hibernate4, so you should use the same value.

Sources:
Check this project out: https://github.com/vaadin-on-grails/sass-compilation and don't forget to buy the book Vaadin on Grails, it has lots of information related.